# Images, sizes and different screens (fragmentation)

Tags: android, image, screen, dpi

I have a logo to put in a splashscreen. Currently, the image size is 960x320 pixels. I have read the developers google post, of the supported screens, but I don't have any idea of what size need to be in a ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi.

I see a table in another answer that says:

```
ldpi x0.75
mdpi x1.00
hdpi x2.00
```

I don't know if this is true or not. Could someone shed some light? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use android dpi (http://coh.io/adpi/) calculator to calculate image size for different resolution

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it now.

Comment: The website told me I had to wait a while to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So take 960x320 as your **base** density (1x = mdpi).

To get to the other ones you multiply the base size by the other sizes.

So to get to hdpi multiply you **base** by 1.5, 960x320:

```
960 x 1.5 = 1440
320 x 1.5 = 480
```

This applies from your base density which is generally mdpi.

```
ldpi = 960 x 0.75 and 320 x 0.75
mdpi = 960 x 1.0 and 320 x 1.0
hdpi = 960 x 1.5 and 320 x 1.5
xhdpi = 960 x 2.0 and 320 x 2.0
xxhdpi = 960 x 3.0 and 320 x 3.0
```

And so forth. Generally its best to use a calculator until you understand in more detail why they need to be like that.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. My image has 150dp in Photoshop, but I see that the ic_launcher icon is 72dp. Can I use this dp? or I need to set to 72?  Thanks

Comment: Do you mean dp or dpi?

Comment: Personally this cheat sheet explains alot: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#screen-densities-and-icon-dimensions

Comment: dp in Photoshop when you create a image, it ask you for a width, height and dp.

Comment: Thanks for the cheat sheet.

Comment: dp in photoshop doesnt mean anything unless you are designing to a physical size (inch/cm etc). As long as you specify the correct size (and export the correct size) in px then you can ignore the dpi setting in photoshop. Basically leave Photoshop to 72(the default I think) and just adjust the image size in pixels.